# How to add (concatenate) two Google.Protobuf.ByteStrings? C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I had not found a way of adding two bytestrings in google documentation. I tried to convert them to strings, concatenate, than convert back. But it gets stuck on conversion back to ByteString.

```
if (someList.Count > 3)
{
    var bigString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
    {
        string partString= someList.ElementAt(i).ToBase64();
        bigString += partString;
        Logger.Write($"{i}");
    }
    Logger.Write("here");
    var chunk = ByteString.FromBase64(bigString);
    Logger.Write("here2");
    SomeFunc(chunk);
    someList.Clear();
}
```

It gets "here", but never to "here2".

UPD: ByteStrings in someList contain WaveIn audioData

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would definitely *not* suggest converting to base64 and back - there's no need for that, and it causes issues as base64 strings aren't naturally joinable like this due to padding.

It looks like you're not actually trying to concatenate *two* ByteStrings, but some arbitrary number. I'd suggest writing them all to a `MemoryStream`, then creating a new `ByteString` from that:

```cs
using var tempStream = new MemoryStream();
foreach (var byteString in someList)
{
    byteString.WriteTo(tempStream);
}
tempStream.Position = 0;
var combinedString = ByteString.FromStream(tempStream);
```